# Have url with pk or id to redirect to update page in Django error message

Tags: django

I've created an app, and on the CreateView page, the Submit button works fine to create a new S Reference. I also created an error message if the input value matches an existing Reference. I created button in the error message part and tried to link it to update the page to update these reference fields, like primary contact. I tried many options but have not got right code for the argument with pk or id to get individual record update page.

this is the url in error message.

I tried quite few pk, id options, none of them works.

```
'pk'=self.pk; 

{'pk'=self.pk};

 object.id
```

some code as below

models.py

```
class LNOrder(models.Model):

reference_number = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True, null=True, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This reference already exists."})


primary_contact = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('lfcnotifier', LNCreateView.as_view(), name='lnorder_create'), 
    path('lfcnotifier/<int:pk>', LNDetailView.as_view(), name='lnorder_detail'),
    path('lfcnotifier/<int:pk>/update/', LNUpdateView.as_view(), name='lnorder_update'),
]
```

template

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend w-225px">
  <label class="input-group-text w-100">S Reference</label>
  </div>
  <input name="reference_number" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your S Reference"/>

  <button class="btn btn-primary cardshadow " data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to submit" style="width:200px;" type="submit">submit</button>

{%for field in form %}

{% for error in field.errors %}

{{ error }} <a href="{% url 'lnorder_update' 'pk'=self.pk %}"  class="shadow-sm col-sm-4 btn-block btn btn-primary mt-0">Update Request</a>

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Views.py

```
class LNCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):

    model = LNOrder

    template_name = 'lfcnotifier/lnorder_create.html'

    form_class = LNOrderForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

I expect when users click on Update Request button, it'll open the update page to edit the individual reference.

but I got message "Could not parse the remainder: '=self.pk' from ''pk'=self.pk'". 
I get slightly different messages when I try the above different options.

I would like to have the right code for the URL to update the page when the Update Request button is clicked.

Thanks,

Additional background, I only put some of template code here to save space. They are in form section. If I use the following code

`<a href="{% url 'lnorder_list' %}"  class="shadow-sm col-sm-4 btn-block btn btn-primary mt-0">Update Request</a>`

instead of

```
<a href="{% url 'lnorder_update' 'pk'=self.pk %}"  class="shadow-sm col-sm-4 btn-block btn btn-primary mt-0">Update Request</a>
```

it can open the full list page without issue. I can go to update page from full list page without issue. But I want to open update page from here directly other than have one more step.

Comment: Where is your view for update?Which view is rendering this template you have shown above?Show us that view

Comment: The UpdateView is ok. As the additional background I added and the urls, I can go to the view from full list page without issue. Just have issue to open the update page directly from create page when the input reference already exits in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is all kinds of confused.

For a start, you can't use a string on the left-hand side of an expression, either in pure Python or in Django templates.

But secondly, you don't have anything called `self` there. What you do have would be passed from the view; however it's not clear from the code you have posted which actual view this is. It doesn't seem to be that CreateView, because you are linking to the update. But assuming it's actually the `LNDetailView`, and assuming that that actually is a DetailView, you have access to the current object in the template exactly as `object`.

So you would do:

```
{% url 'lnorder_update' pk=object.pk %}
```

**However** again, this makes no sense to actually do. You can't submit a form via an `a`. You need a `<form>` element with a button.

Comment: I've added additional background. Thanks for your reply, but when I tried pk=object.pk, it shows error: Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'lnorder_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['lfcnotifier\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/update\\/$']